# open URLS in new window on page load

Tags: jquery, html

```
<ul class="test">
    <li>
        <a href="abc.com">abc.com</a>
        <a href="xyz.com">xyz.com</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How we can open above URL in new window on page load.

Comment: Do you mean when you open the page with this html it will open the other  windows without clicking on anything?

Comment: @Dhunt: yes it will open, without clicking on links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**I got the solution: Thanks to everyone for your help.**

<ul class="test">
    <li>
        <a href="abc.com">abc.com</a>
        <a href="xyz.com">xyz.com</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type='text/javascript' >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".test li a").each(function(){
            url = $(this).attr("href");
            window.open(url,'_blank')
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the a-tags`target="_blank"`

```
<ul class="test">
    <li>
        <a href="abc.com" target="_blank">abc.com</a>
        <a href="xyz.com" target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: **on page load** ? Did you miss that ?

Comment: Use '<body onload="myFunction()">' where myFunction() is your js function that will do what you tell it. In this example open your links. Or do you not know how to write the js? I think its ot specified enough

Comment: `target="_blank"` is not the solution for specified question!

Answer (score 1):

> Select the `a` elements using specific selector and use `window.open` for the `href` attribute of those elements

```
$('a').each(function () {
    window.open(this.href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `target="_blank"`

```
<a href="abc.com" target="_blank">abc.com</a>
 <a href="xyz.com" target="_blank">xyz.com</a>
```